# Why is the command in argv[0] rether than the first arg?

Tags: command-line-arguments

Recently a student in a CS lab I TA was ranting about how confusing it was that argv[0] was not the first argument but the command you ran instead (kind of like when they rant about how "stupid" it is that they have to write x == 2 or x == 4 instead of x == 2 or 4 in python), and asked me why they did it. Well, I honestly had no idea why. I don't see any practical purpose to knowing what command was used to execute your program nor a problem with passing an empty list/vector, and google didn't help to resolve this question either.

So my question is why is the executed command itself included in the list/vector of command line arguments?

Comment: You're not prohibited to rename an executable…

Comment: Well no, but I have never seen any case in which one would care until cnicutar pointed out the cases bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing the command line can influence the way the program behaves. As a famous example, `bash` behaves like the classic `sh` if you call it as such (for example using a softlink). Busybox also comes to mind (it really makes heavy use of it).

Comment: I had never really used any of those, but it makes sense to have a single application behave differently like that. Thanks.